# Column 'ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl' does not exist. Rest odata SPOnline

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, odata

I'm trying to get documents from a document library where **ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl** not equal empty, I'm trying something like this:

```
https://my-sharepoint/sites/mysite/_api/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl,Title,File&$expand=File&$filter=ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl ne " "
```

But this give me error Column 'ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user

What am i doing wrong?

If somebody can bring me some help on this i'll appreciate it!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it can be filtered on the request (at least I can't get it to), worst case you omit the filter and skip over the entry in the result set?

Comment: @EricAlexander I have the same problem, can you explain that with more details please?

Comment: @EmmanuelVillegas i forgot to circle back to this, supplied a rough example

Answer (score 2):

I messed around with this for a bit and I don't think the property is filterable. That means you'll have to request a bigger result set and filter it on the success function. It would look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://my-sharepoint/sites/mysite/_api/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl,Title,File&$expand=File",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data){
       $(data.d.results).each(function(){
        if(!this.ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl.length){
            console.log(this);
        };
       });
    },
    error:function(){
        //do something
    }
});
```